# С чего начинать в c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-5

Всем здравствуйте мне 15 лет и я хотел бы быть программистом. У меня есть проблема я хочу изучать c# ASP.NET нашёл курс но там все очень сложно знаю c# на уровне функций ну и классы че-то знаю ну в общем ооп не особо. Вопрос в том с чего начать доучить c# по гайду сакутина и тогда я начну понимать курс по asp.net или просто продолжать долбить asp. Net курс. Кому интересно курс от bhrugen patel asp. Net mvc .Net 5

Comment: Отзывы у курса 4.8

Comment: если ты не знаешь c# как ты собрался учить ASP.NET или .NET? как ты вообще собрался двигаться в этом направлении если ты даже нормально не знаешь функции и ооп. неужели нельзя до этого самому додуматься? неужели это так сложно? или реально сейчас молодежь такая? короче сначала смотришь все видео сакутина от корки до корки и пишешь ВСЕ ЧТО ПИШЕТ ОН. любую строку пишешь и пыташься понять зачем это и как работает. он пишет проект - ты тоже, осмысливаешь его, а потом пытаешься понять его и написать самому, потом делаешь проекты сам, ты должен выучить всю базу c#, функции и ООП потом начни  git

Comment: дальше базы данных и вот потом .NET, WPF, ASP.NET и все остальное, желаю удачи. и вот тебе совет, если у тебя, что-то  не получается изучи это и пытайся решить проблему, не бросай на пол пути. и еще если поймешь что c# это не твое, то пробуй что-то другое может даже вернешься обратно на c#. короче работай и отрабатывай, программирование это скил и умение а не теория

Comment: Спасибо. Прогуглил что таке git не особо понял объясни если не трудно пожалуйста

Comment: Git — это система, которая позволяет сразу нескольким разработчикам сохранять и отслеживать изменения в файлах вашего проекта.

Comment: Что касается создания приложений и сайтов, то здесь Git — обязательный и незаменимый инструмент. Часто бывает так, что внесенное в код исправление рушит работающие части проекта, и даже после отмены этого исправления ситуация не улучшается. Решение — Git. Он защищает ваш проект от подобных неожиданностей и исключает возможность случайного удаления правок или файлов. Благодаря уникальному подходу к хранению данных, Git может быстро откатить проект до рабочего состояния при возникновении ошибок.

Comment: Вам не потребуется выискивать проблемы, которые повлекло за собой добавление изменений, ведь в любой момент можно вернуться к одной из старых версий. Такая система нужна, чтобы люди, участвующие в разработке, могли беспрепятственно «копаться» в коде, не боясь навредить чужим правкам или работе проекта в целом. С помощью Git можно поддерживать рабочую версию и параллельно создавать новые, одной командой сливать их воедино или разделять. Этот инструмент ускоряет процесс разработки и делает его более эффективным.

Comment: Начать - с проекта, с его идеи. Ну а после уже начинать сразу его реализовывать. Условно, банальный калькулятор, вот сделали консольный проект, написали там пару строк кода в одном методе, вот у вас уже сложение, написали еще пару строк, вот уже умножение, и так весь функционал. После, анализируем это все и отвечаем сами себе "что не так?", скорей всего увидите много фигово структурированного кода, много дубликатов, не понравиться то, что все в одну кашу. Имея это, начните "рефакторинг", разбейте на классы и методы (вот вам и ооп), уйдите в абстракцию (привет SOLID), ну и так далее.

Comment: Как получите базу на живом проекте, улучшайте его, к примеру, сделайте UI на интересующей вас технологии, также, первый блин косо, чисто понять основу, потом рефакторинг и создание чего-то уже адекватного. Как сделаете, поймете, изучите, продвигайтесь дальше, улучшайте проект. К примеру, можете начать работать с сервером, сделайте его для калькулятора, поднимите и реализуйте интерфейс для взаимодействия, напишите клиента под это все. Ну и опять по кругу, тяп-ляп, изучили, по новой. Далее попробуйте работу с базой, сохраняйте результаты вычислений в базу. Так, на живом примере, вы изучите язык.